# reprojection: wms cascading or client side js?

Tags: geoserver, wms, map-projections

I would like to use the wms of the italian cadastre. The wms is in epsg:6706 so I need a re-projection on the fly in wgs84.
I have two possibilities: 1) using gesoerver cascading wms to reproject otf
2) using js client-side re-projection library (for example proj4js).

What are the PROS/CONS?

In the first case, is geoserver very stressed? Do I need to scale out respect to wms cascading 'keep native' configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the re-projection on the client side to avoid having to deal with server overload issues.  Many mapping libraries support client side re-projection for example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html

https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=client-projection